# jQuery: function which still acts on old selection

Tags: jquery, animation, selection

I have a function that acts on a selection (passed by means of the argument 'sel'): when I hover with the mouse upon the items in the selection, another element in the same selection ('.extLink') is animated.
The function is:

```
function animo(sel) { 
    sel.hover(      
        function () {       
            $('.extLink').stop().animate({right: '-5px'}, 'fast');      
        },          
        function () {       
            $('.extLink').stop().animate({right: '0'}, 'fast');         
        }       
    );  
}
```

The selection changes by clicking on certain elements of the page. But it happens that, despite the selection correctly changes, the function continues to work even on items that were part of previous selections, ie .extLink is animated when I pass on these items too.

I made some tests and saw that the selection is done properly. What could therefore be the cause of this behavior? What I'm doing wrong?

The HTML on which the function acts is as follows (extracted from the DOM):

```
<ul>
<li class="ref-1">310 Raccolte di statistiche generali</li>
<li class="ref-1">320 Scienza politica</li>
<li class="ref-2 attivo">330 Economia </li>
<li class="ref-2 attivo">340 Diritto
    <div class="quadri">
        <ul>
            <li>328 Il processo legislativo</li>
            <li>330 Economia</li>
            <li>340 Diritto</li>
        </ul>
        <a class="extLink" href="http://www...">...</a>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="ref-3">350 Amministrazione pubblica; arte militare</li>
<li class="ref-3">360 Problemi e servizi sociali; associazioni</li>
</ul>
```

It works as following:

- clicking on a X element (elsewhere) of the page, the class 'attivo' is added to the li.ref-x (in the example li.ref-2);
- at the same time, the div.quadri is cloned from its original position in the page and appended to the last li.attivo;
- inside the div.quadri there is a.extLink;
- the selection I pass to the animo() function is li.attivo, so when I move the mouse on the li.attivo elements (and consequently on div.quadri too) a.extLink is animated.

All this works well, the problem comes after:

- when I click a Y element of the page, the class 'attivo' is added to li.ref-y (e.g li.ref-3) and removed from li.ref-x, then the div.quadri is removed from li.ref-x and a different div.quadri is cloned inside li.ref-y;
- now a.extLink is animated when I move the mouse not only on li.ref-y (i.e. li.attivo) but also on li.ref-x though they haven't the class 'attivo' anymore.

Comment: if you pass `.extLink` as `sel` all classes will animate, how do you call `animo()` ?

Comment: I've added some HTML and description in my first question

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `attivo` class from elements after you've selected them and registered event listeners on them won't stop the listeners from being called, and your listeners perform the animation based only on class name `extLink`, not context.  Try something like one of these:

## Remove listeners from previous selection

```
var previous_sel = $();

function animo( sel ) { 

  // Assumes jQuery 1.7

  previous_sel.off( "mouseenter mouseleave" );

  previous_sel = sel;

  // ... rest of your current function

}
```

## Use delegated registrations

This will only call the listeners for elements that have class `attivo` at the time the event occurs.

```
function animo() {

  // Use appropriate selector to get the relevant UL

  var ul = $( "ul" );

  var selector = "li.attivo";


  ul.on( "mouseenter", selector, function () {       

    ul.find( selector + ' .extLink' ).stop().animate(

      { right : '-5px' }, 'fast'

    );      

  } );


  ul.on( "mouseleave", selector, function () {       

    ul.find( selector + ' .extLink' ).stop().animate(

      { right : '0' }, 'fast'

    );     

  } );

}
// animo
```

## Limit the context

Limit the context to `extLink`s within `sel`.

```
function animo( sel ) { 

  sel.hover(      

    function () {       

      sel.find( '.extLink' ).stop().animate( { right : '-5px' }, 'fast' );      

    },          


    function () {       

      sel.find( '.extLink' ).stop().animate( { right : '0' }, 'fast' );         

    }       

  );  

}
```